# When during IVF are the parents' thoughts determining the level of the soul of their baby

Tags: pregnancy-birth, kavana-intent

I have read that the thoughts of a couple during marital relations does determine and effect the level of the soul they draw down for their baby.  What about a couple using IVF to conceive? When during the IVF process are the parents thoughts doing that same thing?  Is it their thoughts at the time  the egg and seed join in the Petri dish?  Is it their thoughts when the egg is placed back in the mother's womb?  Or some other time?

Edit to add:  I am asking about using the mother's own egg and the father's own sperm.  No donors no surrogate.

Comment: Not everything that you heard somewhere must be right.

Comment: @Ilja see Tanya chapter 2 and the sources brought there, Sefer Hagilgulim, and all over Sifrei Kabbalah.